# EditorTemplates and ViewData

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc-editor-templates

I have a ton of Forms that follow the common format of Label: Control. I decided instead of having pages of the following:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
     <div class="span4">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Prop1)
    </div>
    <div class="span8">
       @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Prop1)
    </div>
</div>
```

I would create an editor template to hold this pattern, and select the correct default control. Of course, a teammate immediately pointed out that hardcoding the spans was not helpful, so I added a few custom ViewData fields such as "labelSpan".

The real problem comes to this:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m, new { @class = @ViewData["class"], style = @ViewData["style"], 
id = @ViewData["id"]... etc })
```

So question 1: How do I consolidate that to pass through directly without having to specify every property?

Question 2: How do I do it in a way such that the following does not conflict?

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m, new { @class = @ViewData["LabelClass"], style = @ViewData["LabelStyle"] })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using `ViewData`, you'll want to use `ModelMetadata`. If you create a custom `ModelMetadataProvider`, you can override the CreateMetadata method to add the appropriate values to the `AdditionalAttributes` and then you can later query those values.

```
    protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes,
                                                    Type containerType, Func<object> modelAccessor,
                                                    Type modelType, string propertyName)
    {
        var metadata = base.CreateMetadata(attributes, containerType, modelAccessor, modelType, propertyName);
        var labelSpan = "span4"; // do whatever logic you need to.
        metadata.AdditionalValues.Add("labelSpan", labelSpan);
        ...
        return metadata;
    }
```

Then you consume the metadata in your editor templates. The pattern that I've found to work is to only put the labels in your `Object.cshtml` editor template:

```
@{
    var visibleProperties = ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.Where(pm => pm.ShowForEdit && !ViewData.TemplateInfo.Visited(pm)).ToList();
    var noHtmlProps = visibleProperties.Where(pm => pm.HideSurroundingHtml).ToList();
    var normalProperties = visibleProperties.Where(pm => !pm.HideSurroundingHtml).ToList();
    foreach (var prop in normalProperties)
    {
        <div class="row-fluid">
            @Html.Label(prop.PropertyName, prop.DisplayName, 
                new{@class=ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["labelSpan"]})

            @(prop.IsReadOnly 
                ? Html.Display(prop.PropertyName) 
                : Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName))
            @Html.ValidationMessage(prop.PropertyName)
        </div>
    }
    // Output hidden properties at the end
    foreach (var prop in noHtmlProps)
    {
        @Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName)
    } 
}
```

Then you use your other types' editor templates to determine which control to use. For example, `String.cshtml` might look like this:

```
@Html.TextBox(string.Empty, ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue,
    new{@class = ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["valueSpan"]})
```